# How to offset the center point in MapView

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

How to offset the center point in MapView.
All these methods animated map on (center center position)

animateToRegion
animateToCoordinate
fitToElements
fitToSuppliedMarkers
Only this one **fitToCoordinates** allows to manipulate with offset position, but it doesn't work correctly with one coordinate.

How can I playing with offset using **animateToRegion** or another method

Thx

Answer (score 3):

The official docs recomands to use `mapPadding` for that. It adds custom padding to each side of the map. Useful when map elements/markers are obscured.

For example :
`mapPadding={{top: 100, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0}}`

See: [MapView Component API](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#mapview--component-api)